# Run sql command line, issue. Creating tables

Tags: sql, oracle, create-table

I'm trying to create a table in run sql command line of oracle database 11 xe.

My problem is when I finish typing my code:

```
create table vigilantes(
idVigilantes integer(3) not null,
nombre varchar(100) not null,
paterno varchar(100) not null,
materno varchar(100) not null,
id_caseta integer(3) null,
id_turno integer(3) null,
edad integer(3) not null,
id_genero integer(1) not null,
idEmpresa integer(3) not null,
constraint pk_idVigilantes PRIMARY KEY (idVigilantes)
constraint fk_id_caseta FOREIGN KEY (id_caseta)
references Caseta(id_caseta)
constraint fk_id_turno FOREIGN KEY(id_turno)
references Turno(id_turno)
constraint fk_id_genero FOREIGN KEY(id_genero)
references Generos(id_genero)
constraint fk_idEmpresa FOREIGN KEY(idEmpresa)
references Empresa(idEmpresa)
);
```

I get "ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis" issue.
I read that this is often caused by not defining a value.
e.g:

```
create table vigilantes(
idVigilantes integer not null,
.......
```

But still no solution here.
Any help or clue will be a lot of help.

Comment: Please pay attention to tags (when you post - they are at the bottom); the web sites adds a few random ones, it added MySQL and Database for you. Make sure you edit that part to leave just the ones that are relevant. I'll do it for you now, but please remember in the future. Thanks!

Comment: oh, now i understand this. Thank you. Will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing comma after constraints. Also, `integer` has no precision.

```
create table vigilantes (
    idVigilantes integer not null,
    nombre varchar(100) not null,
    paterno varchar(100) not null,
    materno varchar(100) not null,
    id_caseta integer null,
    id_turno integer null,
    edad integer not null,
    id_genero integer not null,
    idEmpresa integer not null,
    constraint pk_idVigilantes primary key (idVigilantes),
    constraint fk_id_caseta foreign key (id_caseta) references Caseta(id_caseta),
    constraint fk_id_turno foreign key (id_turno) references Turno(id_turno),
    constraint fk_id_genero foreign key (id_genero) references Generos(id_genero),
    constraint fk_idEmpresa foreign key (idEmpresa) references Empresa(idEmpresa)
    );
```

If you must define precision, use `number` datatype:

```
create table vigilantes (
    idVigilantes number(3, 0) not null,
    nombre varchar(100) not null,
    paterno varchar(100) not null,
    materno varchar(100) not null,
    id_caseta number(3, 0) null,
    id_turno number(3, 0) null,
    edad number(3, 0) not null,
    id_genero number(1, 0) not null,
    idEmpresa number(3, 0) not null,
    constraint pk_idVigilantes primary key (idVigilantes),
    constraint fk_id_caseta foreign key (id_caseta) references Caseta(id_caseta),
    constraint fk_id_turno foreign key (id_turno) references Turno(id_turno),
    constraint fk_id_genero foreign key (id_genero) references Generos(id_genero),
    constraint fk_idEmpresa foreign key (idEmpresa) references Empresa(idEmpresa)
    );
```

Comment: I tried with both my code and your reply now with the commas after constranis, Also u missed a comma in the last constraint for fk but still getting the "ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis".

Comment: @Edgarecko7 - there won't be any comma after last constraint. Also, missed the integer datatype (size defined). Updated the answer. Please try now?

Comment: I tried but now i got invalid datatype.
I changed the integer type to number as you said.

Comment: You'll need to have same data type for the columns of other tables that are being referred in the foreign key constraints. I tried it without the FK and both worked for me.

Comment: I had to check all the database design and there were a lot of errors from the 1 i got. Now i re-typed all the tables, there are just 5, but now, thanks to you, with your help about the commas and datatypes i solved the issue. Many thanks. GurV.